# Make migrating a question a community effort

Tags: feature-request, migration

As a Linux system administrator/DevOps/whatever, I use Stack Overflow all the time in my work. I also (to a much lesser extent) use Server Fault and the *Unix & Linux* Stack Exchange. The reason I don't use the latter two more often is that most of the questions I want answered were answered years ago before those new branches emerged, and not every question that could/should be moved over has been.

I'm not really surprised, since migrating a question has to be done by the moderators. That would be an insane amount of work. What if we distributed that workload a bit?

I propose, besides being able to upvote/downvote a question, you could also vote to have it migrated to another Stack Exchange site. Then the moderators could easily find the questions that most need to be migrated by their vote-count, or we could even have them auto-migrate if the voting ratio hits some threshold.

Comment: The community can migrate questions to Super User.  22 have been migrated in the last 90 days.  Migrations to Server Fault were disabled years ago because of how bad the community was at determining what questions would be appropriate to migrate there.

Comment: [The statistics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQRkg.png) don't look good when we have sane mods governing the process. Putting this in hands of the community probably make the parties  on either side of the migration unhappy.

Comment: @Servy, how the community can migrate questions to Super User? Is it “flag to moderator” or something else?

Comment: Close > Belongs elsewhere > migrate to [site name from a specific list].

Comment: For a few sites per site, you can VTC questions that arn't too old as a normal user. That said if its on topic for more than one site, it can stay where it is now.

Comment: @nij, actually on SO : Closing>Off-Topic>This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

Comment: Yeah, something like that. I skipped a couple of steps, I don't have all the pathways memorised yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can already vote to close to about 5 sites that are periodically and irregularly reviewed for usefulness. Flagging to migrate is only really if you don't have that site as a migration target. Mods can't migrate questions that are too old, so outside of a wider range of migration targets we can't do anything you can't.

That is to say, the community can *already* migrate posts.

That said, if its on topic on more than one site, it should stay where it is.

Practically, as a mod on an older, broader site, we hardly if ever migrate, and the workload for migration flags isn't that heavy.

Comment: The wording “Closing>Off-Topic>This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network” doesn’t include the word “migrate” which makes it harder to discover, how to vote to migrate.

Comment: Yanno? That's a pretty valid complaint that a long time user will/does take for granted.